# Combobox with titles for iOS

Tags: ios, combobox

What is the best way to create combobox with titles as on image?

[image: combobox with titles]

Comment: UITableView + Search Bar

Comment: good idea, thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Rob says in his comment, that's a sectioned `UITableView` with a search bar (`UISearchController`)

Comment: good idea, thanks for the help